# Fixed point set of diffeomorphism is a submanifold

Tags: differential-topology, sg.symplectic-geometry

I am in the following setting: Let $(\Sigma,\alpha\vert_\Sigma)$ be a compact regular energy surface of restricted contact type in an exact Hamiltonian manifold $(M,d\alpha,H)$. Given $\varphi \in \operatorname{Symp}(M,d\alpha)$ such that $\varphi(\Sigma) = \Sigma$, we can consider the set
$$\operatorname{Fix}(\varphi\vert_\Sigma) \subseteq \Sigma$$ of fixed point of $\varphi$ restricted to $\Sigma$. **Is it true that the set of fixed point is an embedded submanifold?** More generally, we may ask if the fixed point set of a diffeomorphism is a submanifold.

Some thoughts: In general, if $G$ is a compact Lie group acting on a smooth manifold, then the fixed point set is an embedded submanifold. Thus if $\varphi$ is an involution, we have that $\operatorname{Fix}(\varphi\vert_\Sigma)$ is an embedded submanifold of $\Sigma$.

**Moreover, can there anything be said about the geometry of the fixed point set?**

Comment: I don't know about your question (because I didn't try to construct examples though I imagine they are plentiful). The fixed point set of a diffeomorphism need not be an embedded submanifold. There are diffeomorphisms of the circle whose fixed point set is a Cantor set (exercise: construct one). 

If you are hoping to prove that this fixed set is a smooth manifold in a particular case you probably ought to try to show that in your example, your particular diffeomorphism is the action of a particular element of a compact Lie group acting smoothly.

Comment: For the general case of a diffeomorphism, how about this? $$(r,\theta)\to(r,\theta+(1-\exp(-r^2))\sin(2\theta)/2)$$ The first factor in the product makes it smooth at the origin; the second factor makes it have fixed points only on the coordinate axes.

Comment: @MikeMiller. many thanks for your comment! I suspected that the general case is false. I think that this also might be the case in my specialised situation...